# ngcontroller in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having some trouble understanding how to use ng-controller. I've a form controller in eventController.js.

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="eventController.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<div>
<h3>My Event:<i>{{event.name}}</i></h3>
</div>
<div ng-controller="formController">
<form >
<label>Event Name:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="event.name" placeholder="Event Name">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the heading even.name is not getting displayed when I'm using ng-controller="formController" in that division otherwise its working fine.
When I use ng-controller on the whole page as a division then I get {{event.name}} and not the content.

How can I display the content of event.name and also use the controller on form together ?

What mistake am I making ?

Answer (score 3):

The `event.name` property is only set within the **scope** of the controller being used. In your case, the `<div>` tag introduces a new scope. Within it, `{{event.name}}` will be data-bound to and replaced by the value of `event.name`.

In your code example, the `<h3>` tag lives outside of the scope defined by `<div ng-controller="formController">`, so `{{event.name}}` won't be data-bound against your model property.

To solve your problem, put the `ng-controller` attribute on a common ancestor element of your heading and the form, like that:

```
<div ng-controller="formController">
    <div>
        <h3>My Event:<i>{{event.name}}</i></h3>
    </div>
    <form >
        <label>Event Name:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="event.name" placeholder="Event Name" />
    </form>
</div>
```

For a slightly more complex example, check out the documentation: [AngularJS: ngController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angController#Example).

Comment: I tried that earlier, but I'm getting {{event.name}} and not the binded data

<body> 
    <div ng-controller="formController">
        <div>
        <h3>My Event:<i>{{event.name}}</i></h3>
        </div>
        <form >
            <label>Event Name:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="event.name" placeholder="Event Name">

Comment: @Anathema.Imbued Take a look at this JSFiddle showing that the solution is indeed working: http://jsfiddle.net/tAnNp/.